# Correct use of var x=prompt()?

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, var, prompt

I'm trying to create a simple game using strictly prompts. The game will ask you a question via prompt onclick. The prompt asks you a question, and you will type in the blank field your 'guess'. If you guess right, it will prompt again saying "You win!", and if you guess wrong, it will prompt "Try again!" with the following question inside the same prompt. There are five guesses, and if you don't guess by the end, a prompt will appear "You lose!"

That's the gist. The if else statement and the majority of the function code here came straight from my instructor, but I'm not sure what I need in order for the prompt to show up "You're right!". I've tried various things, but every time I type in the correct answer in the prompt to test it comes up Null.

If I can figure out how to get the game to end by getting the correct answer, then I think I should be able to figure out how to repeat the question prompt functions.

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Camping Trip!</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link type="style" src="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center><h1>"I'm going on a camping trip..."</h1></center>
<br>
<!-- This is the Start Game button that begins the game-->

<center>  
    <button onclick="gamePlay()">Start Game!</button>
</center>
    
<!-- This is the Tutorial button that shows the rules-->

<br>

<center>
    <button id="show"onclick="startTutorial()">Show Tutorial</button>
        <p id="rules"></p>
</center>
<!-- This is the Hide Tutorial Button-->    
<center>
    <button id="hide">Hide Tutorial</button>
</center>

<!-- This is the Camping Trip picture-->
    
<center>
<img class="irc_mi" style="margin-top: 141px;" src="http://i10.photobucket.com/albums/a146/dizzybint78/tent.gif" width="600" height="333">
</center>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
alert("Welcome to the Caming Trip game!");

function startTutorial() {
    document.getElementById("rules").innerHTML = "<strong>Rules:</strong><br><br>The rules are simple! Initially, you will be given a clue, and an attempt to answer. There will be five clues. All five clues will follow a certain pattern, trait, or category. It's up to you to find out what that is!";
}
    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
        $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
    
var gameState = 0;
    
function gamePlay() {
if (gameState == 0) { 
gameQ1(); 
}
else if (gameState == 1) {
gameQ2();
}
else if (gameState == 2) {
gameQ3();
}
else if (gameState == 3) {
gameQ4();
}
else if (gameState == 4) {
gameQ5();
}
else if (gameState == 5) {
prompt("Sorry! Try Again!");
 }
}

function gameQ1() {
var answer = "fruit"
var guess=prompt("I'm going on a camping trip, and I'm bringing an Apple.\n\nAnswer:"); {
return prompt(guess);
}
if (prompt.guess == answer) {
alert("You've Won!");
document.refresh;
}
else (gameState ++)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have something that looks like an attempt at a function code block after the prompt, that shouldn't be there. It's interpreted as an inline code block so the `return` will exit the `gameQ1` function.

```
var guess=prompt("I'm going on a camping trip, and I'm bringing an Apple.\n\nAnswer:"); {
return prompt(guess);
}
```

should be just:

```
var guess=prompt("I'm going on a camping trip, and I'm bringing an Apple.\n\nAnswer:");
```

When you are checking the result you are using the variable as if it was a property of the `prompt` function object. It's just a variable.

```
if (prompt.guess == answer) {
```

should be:

```
if (guess == answer) {
```

When you try to reload the page you are just accessing the function, not calling it.

```
document.refresh;
```

should be:

```
document.refresh();
```

That should get you started. I can tell you that you will need a loop somewhere to keep running the code in the `gamePlay` function over and over so that you can go through the game states.

Comment: Thanks a ton Guffa. I'm actually a first year Media student five weeks in. I'm sure there will be holes in my code for the foreseeable future but for the most part I feel I've been able to figure out most of my issues through trial and error. This one not so much haha. Getting there!